# REGEXP_EXTRACT with URL in Hive

Tags: regex, hive

I want to extract a word between '/bla-bla-bla/' and 'a12345' in the URL, which is `"this-is-the-word"` using regexp_extract in Hive.

> INPUT: www.website.com/bla-bla-bla/this-is-the-word.a12345.anotherword.blabla
>
> DESIRED OUTPUT: this-is-the-word

I've tried below, but none of them worked. What RegEx will achieve my desired output from this input?

```
regexp_extract(URL,'^.*[/]bla[-]bla[-]bla[/]([a-z]+)\\.(a([0-9]+))*$',1)
regexp_extract(URL,'^.*[/]bla-bla-bla[/]([a-z]*)[.]a([0-9]+)*$',1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
regexp_extract(URL,'^.*/bla-bla-bla/([^/.]+)\.a[0-9].*$', 1)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6993Rm/1)

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `/bla-bla-bla/` - a literal `/bla-bla-bla/` substring
- `([^/.]+)` - Group 1 (what you will get since the next argument is `1`): 1 or more chars other than `/` and `.`
- `\.a` - a `.a` substring
- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `.*$` - the rest of the string to its end.